# How to add a background component under IntroSlider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So, I used the IntroSlider package and I have successfully executed it. However, I don't want to use just a simple background color. I wanted to create a background with components on it that I have already created in a separate dart file. How will I e able to combine them? The following are the codes that I have created:

**intro_slider.dart**

```
import 'package:ehatid_driver_app/Screens/Welcome/components/background.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/dot_animation_enum.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/intro_slider.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/slide_object.dart';

import 'signup.dart';

class IntroSliderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroSliderPageState createState() => _IntroSliderPageState();
}

class _IntroSliderPageState extends State<IntroSliderPage> {
  List<Slide> slides = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "More Passengers",
        description:
        "No need to worry about getting passengers, \n as they will be able to connect directly to you",
        pathImage: "assets/images/illus8.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Convenient",
        description: "Efficient way of acquiring new \n passengers for all stray tricycle drivers",
        pathImage: "assets/images/illus2.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Earn More",
        description: "Higher revenue pay for maximizing \n every trip journey",
        pathImage: "assets/images/illus11.png",
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "Accept a Job",
        description: "Register in TODA G5 Terminal and \n experience your first trip.",
        pathImage: "assets/images/ehatid logo.png",
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> renderListCustomTabs() {
    List<Widget> tabs = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      Slide currentSlide = slides[i];
      tabs.add(
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                    child: Image.asset(
                    currentSlide.pathImage.toString(),
                    matchTextDirection: true,
                    height: 250,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: Text(
                    currentSlide.title.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 32, letterSpacing: -2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 3,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    currentSlide.description.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xff646262), letterSpacing: -0.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                    ),
                    maxLines: 3,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return tabs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntroSlider(
      backgroundColorAllSlides: Colors.yellow,
      renderSkipBtn: Text(
        "Skip",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xff8C8C8C)),
      ),
      renderNextBtn: Text(
        "Next",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      renderDoneBtn: Text(
        "Done",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      colorDot: Colors.white,
      sizeDot: 10.0,
      typeDotAnimation: dotSliderAnimation.SIZE_TRANSITION,
      listCustomTabs: this.renderListCustomTabs(),
      scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      onDonePress: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**background.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const Background({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      height: size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/Vector 1.png",
              width: size.width,
            ),
          ),
          child,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the UI im achieving for: The background is in background.dart, while all elements such as text, buttons and textfields are in intro_slider.dart.

**UI:**

[image]

**Vector Image**

[Vector Image for BG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTrrN.png)

Comment: could you please add some ui of what you want?

Comment: @eamirho3ein updated it already, please help

Comment: could you please simplify the code so I can run it? now I can't run this

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: could you please include the background svg file?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I am using a png file for that vector.  I used background color a png file for that detail which is the vector but i'll include it.

Comment: Yes I mean background image file

Comment: Added it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove IntroSlider's `backgroundColorAllSlides`, and set it in `background.dart` like this:

```
Container(
      height: size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.yellow,// <--- add here
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/JTrrN.png",
              width: size.width,
            ),
          ),
          child,
        ],
      ),
    )
```

And then use it like this:

```
Background(
        child: IntroSlider(
          renderSkipBtn: Text(
             "Skip",
             style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xff8C8C8C)),
          ),
          renderNextBtn: Text(
             "Next",
             style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          renderDoneBtn: Text(
             "Done",
             style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          colorDot: Colors.white,
          sizeDot: 10.0,
          typeDotAnimation: dotSliderAnimation.SIZE_TRANSITION,
          listCustomTabs: this.renderListCustomTabs(),
          scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          onDonePress: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => HomePage(),
             ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: where will I insert the above codes?

Comment: in background widget(background.dart)

Comment: How about in intro slider.dart? What do I need to add to access that widget

Comment: Sorry im a bit confused because I am new to flutter, in which part of intro slider.dart will I place the Background given my codes above?

Comment: I updated my answer again, in intro_slider.dart just wrap your IntroSlider with Background. @annyeongk

Comment: Okay i see IT DOES WORK TYSM FOR UR HELP GODBLESS!